# Objective-C, how to redefine NSString in same method?

Tags: objective-c, methods, nsstring

I'm trying to figure out the best way to possibly redefine an NSString within the same method. Basically in the past I've handled them with `[self goSomewhereVoid]` to redefine the string and then return to the method. Is there any other way to do this without leaving the method? thank you.

```
- (void)someMethod(NSString *)theString {

isNumberOne = YES;

NSString *theString = @"something that changes often";
[self goSomewhereVoid:theString];

isNumberTwo = YES;

NSString *theString = @"time to change something"; // <- possible to redefine this?
[self goSomewhereElseVoid:theString];

...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just go:

```
theString = @"new value";
```

Comment: heh. I'll go hide under a rock now; I love when it's that easy :-o Thank you very much!